# Twisted Pair Eithernet

Tags: networking, cat5

I have recently moved into a new home.  I have found that it used to have electrial radiators which have since been removed.  However the cabling is still in the wall (L / N / E)  This cabling uses a different circuit to the normal electric lines.

I am wondering.

Is it possible for me to use the electrical wire as actual cable.  E.g. RX + TX UTP at each end? In theory I could dasy chain each outlet to the next using Just two of the cores.

This in essence would behave like a Token Ring Network - Not unlike modern powerline adapters today.

Can someone confirm if this would actually work?

Comment: packet loss by interference would be horrendous

Comment: If you're just wanting some generic tip and ring connectivity, sure, it would probably be fine.  But I would be hesitant to even use it as speaker wire, let alone for any kind of digital transmission.

Comment: Powerline does sound like a better option, if you still have AC supply to the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted pair is there for a reason - it works as a shield and reduces interference. Is not like people had too much copper and they have decided to waste it and twist network cables "for fun". Lack of it will introduce interference and that will introduce packet loss.
Will it work? Possibly. You have to try it - we don't know how long are those cables, what are they, in which country, what else is close to them...

This question can't be answered without trying first. Do you know anyone with Fluke meters?

And what's wrong with WiFi (AC)?